# Override getters for a set of properties in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'd like to do something like the following:

```
class Properties {
    a = 12;
    b = false;
    c = 'green';
}

@Injectable()
class PropertyService {
    private _properties: Properties;

    constructor(props: Properties) {
        this._properties = props;
    }

    // À la Python...
    __get__(propname): any {
        if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty(this._properties, propname)) {
            return this._properties[propname];
        }

        return undefined;
    }
}
```

The goal is to be able to use this as a service in a library so that an app can do something like:

```
import { appProperties } from './config/properties';
...
    constructor(private props: PropertyService) {
        props.set(appProperties);
    }
```

and, in a library, I can do things like:

```
    constructor(private props: PropertyService) { }

    someMethod() {
        if (this.props.b) {
            ...
        }
    }
```

As far as I'm aware, getters have to be property-specific in Typescript. Am I barking up the wrong tree here?

Comment: what about extending from `Properties` class?

Comment: `class PropertyService  extends Properties {
     setProps(props: Properties) { // the assignment logic for the class properties }
}`